# Como puedo consultar cada campo de una base de datos en java my sql

Tags: java, mysql, mysqldb

estoy haciendo un proyecto en java con mysql que su funcion es adivinar el jugador de futbol que piensa el usuario, en mi base de datos puse varios campos, quiero saber como puedo preguntarle al usuario si su personaje tiene algun campo de mi base de datos y asi relacionarlos con ella, pero no conozco muy bien la forma de usar las librerias de sql

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problemas has tenido? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Investiga y aprende sobre  `JDBC`  y vuelve con una pregunta concreta.